# How to implement drag'n'drop app in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener, android-image

I want to write an app for my thesis that it will have some items/icons and i will drag'n'drop them in a box and then it will make a query in a database and return the result..but i can't find information on how to combine the drag'n'drop with the box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [DroidNova](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html)  You need to delve into the graphics to get it done!

Answer (score 0):

Or this [Simple Drag n Drop on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html)